# What to add in permission_classes for allowing to view the api by only specific group - django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

To make only admin access the API, used - permission_classes = (IsAdminUser, )

But to access the specific group is there anything needed to add to permission_classes, or such a thing is completely not possible with permission_classes. If so how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DjangoModelPermissions` and assign group permissions for the specific model in Django admin. This will work the same way as it works in the admin panel.

Alternatively, if you wish to hard-code the group name (which is not a really good idea, since the group name is specified in the admin and can be changed at any time) in your code, you can roll your own permission class.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class IsGroupUser(BasePermission):
    group = None
    
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        return user.is_authenticated and user.groups.filter(name=self.group).exists()

class IsManager(IsGroupUser):
    group = 'managers'
    
permission_classes = [IsManager]
```

Comment: The code works well. Can u pls provide any sample code for the usage of DjangoModelPermissions

Comment: There is nothing specific, just add it to the permission_classes. Also, there is drf docs to read!

Comment: Please **accept** an answer if it was helpful.